# Format Html Codeblocks like Stack Overflow

Tags: html, markdown, markdownsharp

Is there an open source project out there (written in Java Script or otherwise, for formatting code samples for well-known programming langauges?

I'm trying to create a documentation website that includes code samples.  Here is an example of what my html looks like:

```
<pre><code>//example c#/html/etc code here</code></pre>
```

I'm using MarkDownSharp to format and encode the sample code, but Markdown doesn't handle the coloring.  I notice when adding code samples to Stack Overflow, it automatically colors it in, making it much more readable.

Is this a proprietary technology that SO uses, or is that available somewhere?

Comment: https://github.com/benweet/stackedit and https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown

Answer (score 1):

I think [**CodeMirror**](http://codemirror.net/) is the one you need.

*jsfiddle* is using this libary as well

Comment: Thanks for the lead.  I notice that's its presented as a code editor.  I'm looking for a display-only solution.  Can CodeMirror be configured for that?

Comment: Yes I am sure that is possible. I even think there is a CSS-only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Igor Russkih (Cail Lomecb) created **Colorer** library, see http://colorer.sourceforge.net which has syntax highlighters for many programming languages and formats.

It is available as plugin into `Far Manager` or as standalone easy to use command line tool.

> ...running `colorer -h -ei UTF-8 -eo UTF-16BE -o NAME.HTML yoursource.cpp` will cause highlighted html generation of yoursource.cpp file with output name NAME.HTML, using UTF-8 as input encoding and UTF-16BE as encoding of result file...
>
> <sub>Source: http://colorer.sourceforge.net/consoletools.html</sub>

Answer (score 0):

For JavaScript (your expressed preference), the two most popular are [Prism](http://prismjs.com) and [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org)